# ionic 5 component selector is not applied to html element

Tags: css, ionic4, selector

I have an ionic 5 app for which I built each page using the cmd line, so they were created using the correct structure.

However, when I try to run it, the page styles aren't used, even though the browser shows the css file has been loaded.

I have the following in the .ts page:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-onboard',
  templateUrl: './onboard.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./onboard.page.scss'],
})
```

The html file:

```
<body>
  <app-onboard>
    ...lots of other elements
    <div class="style1">
    </div>
  </app-onboard>
</body>
```

The scss file:

```
app-onboard {
  .style1 {
    color: #ff00ff;
  }
}
```

style1 is on an html element, but it is not applied. However, when I delete the app-onboard wrapper, the style is applied i.e.:

```
.style1 {
  color: #ff00ff;
}
```

Why would the presence of the app-onboard selector prevent the styles from being applied in the page?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a `.` in front of the `app-onboard` in the `scss` file as you're calling the `scss` class instead of the `html` tag like so

```
.app-onboard {
  .style1 {
    color: #ff00ff;
  }
}
```

Hence the reason why the style only applied once you removed it.

If you wish to use the selector as per your current `scss` you'll have to change your `html` file to

```
<body>
  <app-onboard>
    ...lots of other elements
    <div class="style1">
    </div>
  </app-onboard>
</body>
```

I'm assuming the `html` file is outside of the `app-onboard` component and you're calling the component from it.

Comment: Belle, sorry I made a mistake (which I've corrected in my OP). I should have written the html like yours, as that is the correct version. The problem is that, even though app-onboard is an html element, the css styles are still not applied to any of the elements within it. That's what I need to try to figure out how to get working.

Comment: Can you share the codepen or stackblitz sample? are you using the `<app-onboard>` in `onboard.page.html` or in other page? I'm worried  if you're using the `<app-onbboard>` in incorrect page.

Comment: <app-onboard> is auto generated by ionic from the component selector. It is inserted as one of the top level html elements on the page, so it can be used in the css styles to uniquely identify lower level elements on the page. But that's the problem, it doesn't seem to be able to be used in the scss styles in the way that I've shown above, which is the way that the ionic docs show how to use it. So that's why I'm asking if anyone has experienced this problem before and has a solution for it?

Comment: I understand it is auto generated. My point is you won't be able to use the `<app-onboard>` in `onboard.page.html` as it's the html file that defines the component. You can however, use it in other component html file to reuse the component; use in `other.page.html` for instance. It's meant for reusability purpose not to be use in the same component. You can just have `.style-1` in the `onboard.page.scss` file without the `app-onboard` on top as the whole `onboard.page.scss` is already set for `app-onboard`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it when you you say <app-onboard> can only be used in components other than the one in which it is defined. If that's the case, why does ionic add it to both the html and scss files of the same component when it generates a page? If it does that, wouldn't that mean the <app-onboard> component is meant to be used in the onboard.html page and its css?

Comment: It's actually the way how Angular works. The generated `selector` name defines the component 'html tag name`. While the `html` and `scss` defines the building block of the component. The `selector` name is then use to refer to the said component in other component. It's like, the `selector` name is a person name and the `html` and `scss` is what makes up the person. Then other people that needed the person's value just need to call that person by name instead of recreating a new person with the same value. Hence it's not called by itself, because that'll be like some sort of inception.